# /opt/project/Qt/spreadsheet/cell.h:0: Note: No relevant classes found. No output generated

Tags: linux, qt

/opt/project/Qt/spreadsheet/cell.h:0: Note: No relevant classes found. No output generated.
Hi to all, I've centos6.4 in VM.  I am building a project given in book "C++-GUI-Programming-with-Qt-4-1st-ed.pdf". but in book it is by coding and i am building by using GUI.

here is my cell.h file :-

```
#ifndef CELL_H
#define CELL_H

#include <QTableWidgetItem>     
#include <QWidget>

class Cell : public QTableWidgetItem
{

public:
    Cell();

    QTableWidgetItem *clone() const;
    void setData(int role, const QVariant &value);
    QVariant data(int role) const;
    void setFormula(const QString &formula);
    QString formula() const;
    void setDirty();

private:
    QVariant value() const;
    QVariant evalExpression(const QString &str, int &pos) const;
    QVariant evalTerm(const QString &str, int &pos) const;
    QVariant evalFactor(const QString &str, int &pos) const;

    mutable QVariant cachedValue;
    mutable bool cacheIsDirty;
};

#endif // CELL_H
```

and here is its cell.cpp file :-

```
#include "cell.h"
#include <QtWidgets>

Cell::Cell()
{
    setDirty();
}

QTableWidgetItem *Cell::clone() const
{
    return new Cell(*this);
}

void Cell::setData(int role, const QVariant &value)
{
    QTableWidgetItem::setData(role, value);
    if(role == Qt::EditRole)
    {
        setDirty();
    }
}   

QString Cell::formula() const
{
    return data(Qt::EditRole).toString();
}

const QVariant Invalid;

QVariant Cell::data(int role) const
{
    if(role == Qt::DisplayRole)
    {
        if(this->value().isValid())
        return value().toString();
    else
        return "####";
    }
    else if(role == Qt::TextAlignmentRole)
    {
        if(this->value().type() == QVariant::String)
            return int(Qt::AlignCenter| Qt::AlignVCenter);
        else
            return int(Qt::AlignRight | Qt::AlignVCenter);
    }
    else
    {
        return QTableWidgetItem::data(role);
    }
}

void Cell::setFormula(const QString &formula)
{
    setData(Qt::EditRole, formula);
}

void Cell::setDirty()
{
    this->cacheIsDirty = true;
}

QVariant Cell::value() const
{
    if (cacheIsDirty)
    {
        cacheIsDirty = false;

        QString formulaStr = formula();
        if (formulaStr.startsWith('\''))
        {
            cachedValue = formulaStr.mid(1);
        }
        else if (formulaStr.startsWith('='))
        {
            cachedValue = Invalid;
            QString expr = formulaStr.mid(1);
            expr.replace(" ", "");
            expr.append(QChar::Null);

            int pos = 0;
            cachedValue = evalExpression(expr, pos);
            if (expr[pos] != QChar::Null)
                cachedValue = Invalid;
        }
        else
        {
            bool ok;
            double d = formulaStr.toDouble(&ok);
            if (ok)
            {
                cachedValue = d;
            }
            else
            {
                cachedValue = formulaStr;
            }
        }
    }
    return cachedValue;
}

QVariant Cell::evalExpression(const QString &str, int &pos) const
{      
    QVariant result = evalTerm(str, pos);
    while (str[pos] != QChar::Null)
    {
        QChar op = str[pos];
        if (op != '+' && op != '-')
            return result;
        ++pos;

        QVariant term = evalTerm(str, pos);
        if (result.type() == QVariant::Double
                && term.type() == QVariant::Double) 
        {
            if (op == '+') 
            {
                result = result.toDouble() + term.toDouble();
            }
             else 
             {
                result = result.toDouble() - term.toDouble();
             }
        }
        else 
        {
            result = Invalid;
        }   
    }
    return result;
}

QVariant Cell::evalTerm(const QString &str, int &pos) const
{
    QVariant result = evalFactor(str, pos);
    while (str[pos] != QChar::Null) 
    {
        QChar op = str[pos];
        if (op != '*' && op != '/')
            return result;
        ++pos;

        QVariant factor = evalFactor(str, pos);
        if (result.type() == QVariant::Double
                && factor.type() == QVariant::Double) 
        {
            if (op == '*') 
            {
                result = result.toDouble() * factor.toDouble();
            }
            else 
            {
                if (factor.toDouble() == 0.0) 
                {
                    result = Invalid;
                } 
                else 
                {
                    result = result.toDouble() / factor.toDouble();
                }
             }
         } 
         else 
         {
            result = Invalid;
          }
        }
    return result;
    }


QVariant Cell::evalFactor(const QString &str, int &pos) const
{
    QVariant result;
    bool negative = false;

    if (str[pos] == '-') 
    {
        negative = true;
        ++pos;
    }

    if (str[pos] == '(') 
    {
        ++pos;
        result = evalExpression(str, pos);
        if (str[pos] != ')')
            result = Invalid;
        ++pos;
    } 
    else 
    {
        QRegExp regExp("[A-Za-z][1-9][0-9]{0,2}");
        QString token;

        while (str[pos].isLetterOrNumber() || str[pos] == '.') 
        {
            token += str[pos];
            ++pos;
        }

    if (regExp.exactMatch(token)) 
    {
        int column = token[0].toUpper().unicode() - 'A';
        int row = token.mid(1).toInt() - 1;

        Cell *c = static_cast<Cell *>(
                          tableWidget()->item(row, column));
        if (c) 
        {
            result = c->value();
        } 
        else 
        {
            result = 0.0;
        }
     } 
     else 
     {
        bool ok;
        result = token.toDouble(&ok);
        if (!ok)
            result = Invalid;
      }
    }

    if (negative) 
    {
        if (result.type() == QVariant::Double) 
        {
            result = -result.toDouble();
        } 
        else 
        {
        result = Invalid;
        }
    }
 return result;
}
```

output is : like this 
[image]

but it should be :- [image]

of course i am not using toolbar but remaining should work.
how to remove this problem ": No relevant classes found. No output generated."

Comment: What tool is generating this message, is it the moc or something else?

Comment: it is generated  by Qt Creartor

Comment: @markus-nm: You're adorable. I've been working professionally with Qt for the past 15 years. I really have no choice than to learn all the versions when they come out. But more to the point. This message may very well be generated by moc for example when using the Q_OBJECT macro without having anything for the meta object compiler (moc) to actually compile, ie. no slots, signals, etc. But thank you for your input.

Comment: @rahul: Is the cell.cpp in your *.pro/*.qbs file? Meaning is it part of your project? If so, could you post a screenshot with the complete QtCreator output message?

Comment: I did help - besides the the fruitless disussion with you. Yes I did tag you because you asked where OPs message is generated. And, as I said, it's the CC not the MOC. The rest of my comment was not addressed to you, which to me is obvious because you did not reference Qt4 at all.
Anyway the problem OP has is not in his source code (atleast not the one he pasted), but somewhere in his project-setup. Maybe he just forgot to save the file before hitting compile, or is referencing another Cell.h, as the Cell.h pasted above simply cannot produce this warning under normal conditions.